# Find all solutions: $28x \equiv 119 \pmod {33}$ where $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{m}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Find all solutions: $28x \equiv 119 \pmod {33}$ where $x \in
> \mathbb{Z}_{m}$

I'm not sure if it's correct but I did this:

Since $28$ and $33$ are coprime, we have that $\operatorname{gcd}(28,33)=1$

$\implies$ There are integers $x$, $y$ for which $28x+33y=1$

Bringing it to the form $33=28 \cdot 1+5$ and using extended euclid we know that $13$ is the multiplicative inverse of $28$.

Now multiply both sides by $13$:

$$364 x\equiv 1547 \pmod {33}$$

So $$1x \equiv 28 \pmod {33} \implies x=33k+28, k \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

Is it right if I do like this? Any other way to solve it maybe?

Comment: $1547 \mod 33 = 29$, not $28$. So the answer is $33k+29$, not $33k+28$. Otherwise, everything is ok, and I don't think there is a shorter method in general for this problem.

Comment: Ohh thank you I forgot! So this would be correct then? Because solution was asked and I didn't really deliver one, or did I by this last equation you corrected for me? Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, the answer that I have given is correct, and if not for a small  error, you were almost there. So full credit, $+1$ as well from my side for a model question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the exteneded Euclidean algorithm will work generally, but here it is a bit overkill. Reducing everything mod $33\,$ we get $\,-5x\equiv 20\ $ so $\ x\equiv -4\equiv 29,\: $ since $\,5\,$ is invertible so cancellable, being coprime to $33$. Note that we chose the smaller negative rep $\,-5\equiv 28\,$ since doing so generally simplifies matters, e.g. it increases the chance we'll obtain an *exact* division, just as we did above.

You'll get the same answer if you correct your arithmetic, viz. $\,13\cdot 119\equiv 29,\,$ not $\,28.\,$